# Evaluate POST form

Tags: php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<?php
     echo "<h1>LED Steuerung</h1>";
     exec('gpio -1 mode 22 out');
     if(isset($_POST['newstate']))
     {
            $neu  = $_POST['newstate'];
            exec('gpio -1 write 22 $neu');
     }

     $currently = exec('gpio -1 read 22');
     if($currently == '0')
     {
            echo " <p> LED is currently off</p>";
            echo " <form action = 'led.php' method='post'>
                    <intput type ='hidden'  name = 'newstate' value= '1'>
                    <input type = 'submit' value = 'LED einschalten'>
                    </form> ";
     }
     else
     {
            echo " <p> LED is currently on</p>";
            echo " <form action = 'led.php' method='post'>
                    <intput type ='hidden'  name = 'newstate' value= '0'>
                    <input type = 'submit' value = 'LED ausschalten'>
                    </form> ";

     }

?>
```

With this code i want to control a LED on the Raspberry Pi. But what so ever it doesn't work. The form get's called, but it doesn't get evaluated.

The if statement:

```
if(isset($_POST['newstate']))
```

It returns every time false.

Comment: Please use English on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @GergoErdosi Translated it, we just have to hope that he understands at least english

Comment: Change `exec('gpio -1 write 22 $neu');` -> `exec("gpio -1 write 22 $neu");`

Comment: thanks for the awnser, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename `<intput type="hidden">` to INPUT.

That solves your problem.

Comment: Don't forget to tick the answer as solution. Thanks ;)